# Can you set PHP Session cross domain?

Tags: php, session, cross-domain, session-variables

I have a php file on `external-site.com` like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['something'] = "whatever"; 
?>
```

This PHP file I include on a different website `example.com` like this:

```
<script src="http://external-site.com/session.js.php"></script>
```

Does this work? I do **not** want to use the session on `example.com` itself. I only need it for `external-site.com`. So I do **not** want to transfer the session to another domain or anything like that.

If so, in which browser does it work and in which browser it does not?

Comment: You can only pass the textual representation of what the $_SESSION holds, you cannot pass the exact session to another server like this.

Comment: I don't want to pass the session. I only want to use it on `external-site.com`. The php file were I set the session is also on `external-site.com`. However I call the file from `example.com` like mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

The session is identified in a cookie with the session ID. Since you're loading the file with an http:// call, it should create the session and add a cookie with the session id from external-side.com.

However, you're probably going to run into issues with 3rd party cookie permissions doing this, regardless of browser. If your user has 3rd party cookies enabled, you're good. If they have them disabled, then no cookie, and hence no session.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use the session from one site to another. Every site has it's own session ids saved on client's pc.